# Looking for VINO on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, vnc, remote-access, vino

I'm very new so excuse me for this question.

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 on a machine to play with linux and try to include it in my netword (sounds like a good idea to me).

Then I'd like first to be able to access it remotely. I've search here and find that Vino was the good solution for Gnome.

Then I've looked for Vino in Ubuntu Software Center and it said that it was already install (great!). Then look for Vino in Application, didn't find it... Look for it in Help, and it tells to go in Sharing and set some stuff... but I didn't find Sharings too in my server... Maybe I'm an idiot (as a newbie), but could someone illuminate my day with some answers and help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu Desktop, see the screenshots below:

[image: desktop sharing]

[image: enable sharing]

If you have the server edition of Ubuntu, then Vino is not the right tool.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Server edition I didn't mention it sorry. Is there an "HowTo" or a usefull link you could give me to configure it? I'd like to access this server via windows plateform with tools like TightVNC.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying, but I am still not quite sure. ...you've looked for Vino in the Software Center, but the server edition is purely text based (no GUI at all). Can you clarify that as well. On Ubuntu server, there is no desktop to share, so people usually use something called openssh server for remote administration. There are lots of howtos for it.

Comment: I'm lookink for that (about GUI), but hard to find something... Every result are talking about vino server on ubuntu desktop... Then I'm on Vino documentation and then I'll try to search about openssh server for remote administration. Thanks for your help mikewhatever :)

Comment: Well, we can help you with both Vino and ssh, as soon as we know which one applies in you case. That is why I've asked - Do you have the desktop or the server? Do you have the Software Center installed?

Comment: Sorry, I've Ubuntu Server, and Ubuntu Software Center is installed.

Comment: Then I've found the solution. In Terminal, i've typed `vino-preferences`, unchecked the box "You must confirm each access..." and checked "Require the user to enter is password". After that, in Terminal again, typed `dconf-editor`and unchecked Require-encryption in Org>Gnome>Desktop>Remote Access. For dconf-editor it was a thing I found over there for accessing Ubuntu Desktop with VNC. So now that works fine for me. But if you have something better to show me, it would be great.